# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStart android NDK

Tags: java, android

Hi i want to make online radio application in that i have to play aac file for that,
I have copied armeabi folder from http://aacplayer-android.googlecode.com/files/aacplayer-android-r25.zip example,  below is screenshot

[image]

the below code working fine

```
  static {
    System.loadLibrary("aacarray"); 
    System.loadLibrary("mms");
}
```

Which loads library without any error

But when i start to play stream from server by using this code

```
    player = new ArrayAACPlayer(ArrayDecoder.create(Decoder.DECODER_OPENCORE), this, Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(AACPlayer.DEFAULT_AUDIO_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS)), Integer.parseInt(String
            .valueOf(AACPlayer.DEFAULT_DECODE_BUFFER_CAPACITY_MS)));

    try {
        System.out.println("One : "+RADIO_STATION_URL);
        player.playAsync(RADIO_STATION_URL);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i am getting  below error

```
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStart
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at    com.example.xmlparsingex.ArrayDecoder.nativeStart(Native Method)
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.xmlparsingex.ArrayDecoder.start(ArrayDecoder.java:100)
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.xmlparsingex.ArrayAACPlayer.playImpl(ArrayAACPlayer.java:114)
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.xmlparsingex.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:273)
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.xmlparsingex.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:242)
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at com.example.xmlparsingex.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:202)
    02-19 15:15:08.124: E/AndroidRuntime(769):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rename the `ArrayDecoder` class (i.e. it must belong to `com.spoledge.aacplayer` package). You can still use this class as `com.spoledge.aacplayer.ArrayDecoder` from your package. I would advise you not to move any of the aacplayer classes to your package.