# android ndk java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStart

Tags: java, android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

For playing AAC file i have setup NDK and downloaded http://code.google.com/p/aacplayer-android/ code

that source i have downloaded from

```
 svn checkout http://aacplayer-android.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ aacplayer-android-read-only
```

after that i have downloaded player from following code

http://aacplayer-android.googlecode.com/files/aacplayer-android-r25.zip

now i have to use that code into my project so i have create new JNI folder and copy all the code .c and .h file... below is an image

[image]

Then i have run ndk-build command and generated .so files which is looking like below

[image]

Now u can see that this two folder in libs folder and with .so files are created which is looking like below

[image]

Now when i build and run apps using below code every thing is working fine the library is loading with out any java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStart error

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    System.loadLibrary("aacarray"); 
    System.loadLibrary("mms");
```

but when i start to play streaming AAC file below error will generated

```
      02-19 23:13:47.090: W/dalvikvm(847): No implementation found for native Lcom/example/xmlparsingex/ArrayDecoder;.nativeStart (ILcom/example/xmlparsingex/ArrayBufferReader;Lcom/example/xmlparsingex/Decoder$Info;)I
      02-19 23:13:47.100: W/dalvikvm(847): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
      02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
      02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStart
      02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):    at com.example.xmlparsingex.ArrayDecoder.nativeStart(Native Method)
      02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):    at com.example.xmlparsingex.ArrayDecoder.start(ArrayDecoder.java:100)
     02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):     at com.example.xmlparsingex.ArrayAACPlayer.playImpl(ArrayAACPlayer.java:114)
     02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):     at com.example.xmlparsingex.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:273)
     02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):     at com.example.xmlparsingex.AACPlayer.play(AACPlayer.java:242)
     02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):     at com.example.xmlparsingex.AACPlayer$1.run(AACPlayer.java:202)
     02-19 23:13:47.100: E/AndroidRuntime(847):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

please note that i have posted this question which has same error [java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: nativeStart android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954692/java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-nativestart-android-ndk) but this question is not same like this so please do not downvote :(

i Have tried  so much to solve the issue but could not success please any body can help me...

Comment: Your Java calls a native C function named `Java_com_example_xmlparsingex_ArrayDecoder_nativeStart()`. Have you implemented it in your C code?

Comment: Alternatively, call JNI `RegisterNatives` on it.  See also http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-jni.html#faq_ULE .

Comment: Hello Alex Cohan no i have not implemented Java_com_example_x.....

Comment: Alex Cohn Thank you thank you thank you sooooo much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You took the aacplayer classes from original package `com.spoledge.aacplayer` and dropped them into your own package `com.example.xmlparsingex` (probably originated in some Android example). **You can't do that**. Pure Java classes will survive it (supported by Eclipse refactoring), but classes with native methods won't. Native methods are bound to specific function names in native library. If the native library **libaacarray.so** exports a function `Java_com_spoledge_aacplayer_ArrayDecoder_nativeStart`, then the corresponding java class must be `com.spoledge.aacplayer.ArrayDecoder` and there is no way around it. Unless you want to tweak and recompile the native library too.

Comment: Pavel Zdenek Thank you sooooo much :) i have done now it's working :)